# Returning column header corresponding to matched value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

need some help here.. I am looking to retrieve Gender from Sheet 2 corresponding to the name in Sheet 1.

- Step 1 - Match the name in sheet 1 to sheet 2 (not all names in sheet 1 will be in sheet 2, mark NA for non matching names)
- Step 2 - Look for the corresponding gender in sheet 2.
- Step 3 - Retrieve the column header or the last number in the column header (1,2,3...6)

Sheet 1

| Name | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| w | ??? |
| e |  |
| r |  |
| t |  |
| y |  |
| u |  |
| i |  |
| q |  |
| w |  |
| e |  |
| r |  |

Sheet 2

| Name | Male 1 | Female 2 | other 3 | other 4 | other 5 | Do not know 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| w | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| a | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| q | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| r | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| e | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| t | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| y | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| u | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with Office 365 we can use FILTER:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER($F$1:$K$1,INDEX($F$2:$K$9,MATCH(A2,$E$2:$E$9,0),0)=1),"No Match")
```

[image]

---

With older versions we can use another INDEX/MATCH:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$1:$K$1,MATCH(1,INDEX($F$2:$K$9,MATCH(A2,$E$2:$E$9,0),0),0)),"No Match")
```

[image]

Comment: Great help. Thanks. Possible to have just the numbers 1,2...6 as output without the prefix?

Comment: All you do is change the title to what you want output.

Comment: Or better yet, just change the `$F$1:$K$1` reference to `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`

Comment: Could also remove `INDEX()` since `MATCH()` will return this index itself. Something like `=IFERROR(MATCH(1,FILTER(F$2:K$9,E$2:E$9=A2),0),"No Match")`

Comment: Or just the MATCH on the inner INDEX for older versions:  `=IFERROR(MATCH(1,INDEX($F$2:$K$9,MATCH(A2,$E$2:$E$9,0),0),0)),"No Match")` @JvdV

Comment: Thanks.. This worked for me..=IFERROR(INDEX({1,2,3,4,5,6},MATCH(1,INDEX($F$2:$K$9,MATCH(A2,$E$2:$E$9,0),0),0)),"No Match"). I have a follow up, if I have 2 matches.. corresponding to "t" , columns "other 4" and "other 5" have 1, and I would like the output to be 4;5, how can I modify the code to reflect that? Please and thanks.

Comment: @giriokamat follow up questions usually get their own post with a reference back to the original question.  But if you are using that one, easier to do: `=IFERROR(MATCH(1,INDEX($F$2:$K$9,MATCH(A2,$E$2:$E$9,0),0),0)),"No Match")`  No need for the outer INDEX as MATCH will return the relative position in numbers already.

Comment: Still figuring this out. The code works with the INDEX on the outer and MATCH. commands. Does not work without the INDEX on the outside.

Comment: How can I use this code =IFERROR(MATCH(1,INDEX($F$2:$K$9,MATCH(A2,$E$2:$E$9,0),0),0)),"No Match") to index and match on multiple sheets?